# Facebook Conversion Api gives an error message "(#100) The parameter data is required"

Tags: php, facebook

I am just trying to get the most basic test of the Facebook Graph API working. I am using PHP and cURL. I copied the data string directly from the Facebook Payload Helper. Everything appears correct, but I am receiving the message:

> `string(135) "{"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter data is required","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"Age1fgb47kngho3guOkcAcj"}}"`

The message is telling me that the "data" parameter is not set, but you can see that it is set in the data string. See my code below. Any help in debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/<PIXEL ID>/events?access_token=<TOKEN>";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    "content-type: multipart/form-data",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = '{
    "data": [
        {
            "event_name": "Purchase",
            "event_time": '.time().',
            "action_source": "website", 
            "event_id": '.rand(100000, 500000).',
            "user_data": {
                "em": "6b583232e99af45c3b436798f32800a4dd6f3524624ba6507ed8269b53ce82a3",
                "ph": null
            },
            "custom_data": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "value": "37"
            }
        }
    ],
    "test_event_code":"TEST9031"
}';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is the content-type which should be "application/json"